# Error: vx_tensor and VX_TYPE_TENSOR undeclared when installing OPENVX tuorial package

Tags: openvx

I am a newbie of OpenVX and am trying to install the tutorial package for learning. I follow the instruction in [Khronos OpenVX Tutorial Material](https://github.com/rgiduthuri/openvx_tutorial) to build it on my Ubuntu 16.4, the process is as followed.

1----- Download the tutorial package at the above link and extract it to *~/openvx_tutorial* directory

2----- Download and install OpenCV 3.1 library: successful. The output files are placed at *~/opencv/build*.

3----- Install CMAKE: successful

4----- Download and install Open-source OpenVX from AMD: successful

4.1. Download the open source at [Open-source OpenVX on GitHub](https://github.com/GPUOpen-ProfessionalCompute-Libraries/amdovx-core) and extract it to *~/openvx_tutorial/tutorial_exercises/amdovx-core* directory.

4.2. Compiling

```
cd ~/openvx_tutorial/tutorial_exercises/amdovx-core
cmake ../amdovx-core/ -DOpenCV_DIR="~/opencv/build/ -DCMAKE_DISABLE_FIND_PACKAGE_OpenCL=TRUE
make
```

Here is the log.
[image]

5----- Download and Install Khronos OpenVX Resources

5.1. Download the OpenVX 1.1 Sample Implementation at  [Khronos OpenVX Resources](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenVX/sample/openvx_sample_1.1.tar.bz2) and extract it to *~openvx_sample*

5.2. Installing

```
cd ~/openvx_sample
make
make install
```

The output files are at *~/openvx_sample/out/LINUX/x86_64/release*. Then the following test commands are successful

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="~/openvx_sample/out/LINUX/x86_64/release"
cd raw
../out/LINUX/x86_64/release/vx_test
../out/LINUX/x86_64/release/vx_query
../out/LINUX/x86_64/release/vx_example
```

6. Compile the tutorial package

```
cd ~/openvx_tutorial
mkdir build-open-source
cd build-open-source
cmake ../tutorial_exercises
make
```

The the errors happen, reporting that the variable type **vx_tensor** and the value **VX_TYPE_TENSOR** are not declared.
[image]

I have also tried to build the package with QT but the same errors happened. Is there anyone encountered these errors before? How can I fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the [khronos headers v1.2](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenVX/.)

Copy this headers into your `tutorial_exercises/include/VX` and rebuild all.

**PS.** some variables are undefined eg. `VX_TENSOR_FIXED_POINT_POS` & `VX_TENSOR_NUM_OF_DIMS` this should be `VX_TENSOR_FIXED_POINT_POSITION` & `VX_TENSOR_NUMBER_OF_DIMS` respectively.